# Using asp.net membership with sqlite or other provider?

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-membership

Does anyone have any examples of using [Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org) with ASP.NET membership?  I am building a small "drop-in" type web application and don't want to rely on an SQL database for storing user credentials, etc.  Sqlite seems like a good option, and I have been impressed with its performance in [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/); I wouldn't mind using xml as a data store either.

On another note, perhaps asp.net membership isn't a good choice for basic form level security?  The app will not require more then a couple users for those who implement it, and at this time I don't see a need for roles.  My thought of using asp.net membership is simplicity to setup and get running; why build a security class if I don't need to, right?

Any other suggestion are surely welcome; thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am a big fan of SQLlite as well. I would say asp.net membership is good enough for the basic stuff.

Peter at Eggheadcafe has this right article about sqllite, check it out. 
[Article](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20051119.asp)

Comment: According to a recent tweet by Peter, "Somebody else did an even better one. since. Look around." - http://twitter.com/peterbromberg/status/5031854389

I'll update if he replies back, but does anyone know what he's talking about?

Answer (score 7):

It looks like Roger Martin's project - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SQLite-Providers.aspx - is now the recommendation for SQLite connectivity.

This is suggested by Peter Bromberg (http://twitter.com/peterbromberg/status/5031854389) and the next top resource on Google is the above by Roger Martin, who suggests that as the place to get the provider (http://galleryserverpro.blogspot.com/2009/08/new-release-adds-support-for-flash.html#comments).

Seeing as how it's part of a semi-commercial product (and the author is trying to get back to work on it as a full-time job), it seems this will be kept up to date.

EDIT 1: More information about the ordering of released providers for SQLite: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/75/397.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For using the membership provider with other databases look at a [custom membership provider](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=asp.net+custom+membership+provider&btnG=Search)

Answer (score 1):

There's a new, updated source for Roger Martin's SQLiteMembershipProvider

nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteMembershipProvider
sourcecode: https://bitbucket.org/jkuemerle/sqlitemembershipprovider